# What are the Python Web GUI tool

Tags: python-3.x

I have a requirement of building WebUI  ( not GUI but WEB UI ). 
What I want to do is build multiple text editors in a single page with buttons and on the click action of these buttons, text written in each editor needs to be saved in a file and submitted to command line tool

I am new to Python and I want to use some low code WEB UI tool for above purpose, can any one please suggest the best approach for this ?

Comment: You may try flask

Comment: on [Pythons wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) you can get a nice overview of available web frameworks.

Comment: thanks I have already looked at flask as well as Dango, however what I am looking for is low code or no code type tools which can help me building web UI

Answer (score 1):

With [NiceGUI](https://nicegui.io/) you can write such UIs with only a few lines of Python code:

```py
from nicegui import ui

editor = ui.input().props('type=textarea')

def save():
    with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(editor.value)

ui.button('Save', on_click=save)

ui.run()
```

[image]

That's it. No need for HTML, JavaScript, CSS or any web framework like Flask, FastAPI, Django etc.

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers of NiceGUI.)

Comment: It requires python > 3.6